# Chain iterables into a new object but keep their class?

Tags: python, oop, python-itertools, chain, database-cursor

I am working with a cursor object in Python which is basically an iterator. I actually have two of them and need to chain into one. These objects have some methods that I need to use further in the program. The problem is that itertools.chain (which basically does the job) returns a chain object and I don't have access to the cursor methods.

Is there a way to keep its original class so that it is a new object (chained out of two) but having all the initial methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some chaining logic yourself. Let's say you have two iterators of different classes, `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._iter = ((i * i for i in range(n)))
    def __next__(self):
        return next(self._iter)
    def foo_method(self):
        print("Yay, method in Foo was called")


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self._iter = ((i / 2 for i in range(n)))
    def __next__(self):
        return next(self._iter)
    def bar_method(self):
        print("Yay, method in Bar was called")
```

Foo iterators have `.foo_method()` and Bar iterators have `.bar_method()`.

Now let's chain them together:

```
class Chain:
    def __init__(self, *iters):
        self._cursor = 0
        self._iters = iters
    def __next__(self):
        """
        Chain iterators together.
        """
        if self._cursor == len(self._iters):
            raise StopIteration
        try:
            return next(self._iters[self._cursor])
        except StopIteration:
            self._cursor += 1
            return next(self)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        Pass everything unknown to the current iterator in chain.
        """
        if self._cursor == len(self._iters):
            raise ValueError("No current iterator")
        return getattr(self._iters[self._cursor], name)
```

Now if you do something like

```
foo = Foo(3)
bar = Bar(3)

chain = Chain(foo, bar)

print(next(chain))
chain.foo_method()
print(next(chain))
print(next(chain))
print(next(chain))
print(next(chain))
chain.bar_method()
```

the output will be

```
0
Yay, method in Foo was called
1
4
0.0
0.5
Yay, method in Bar was called
```

This does not preserve the class of iterators, but it does allow you to access all the methods of the "current" iterator in chain.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. It basically does work, but the problem I am facing now is that when I call a cursor object method that would call it for a single object. Say I have 2 cursor objects having 13 and 44 items respectively. When I call .count() it will return 13. I can redefine count() method in Chain class but I have other methods like limit() and skip() that are much harder to redefine.

Is there a way to work with a Chain object like a combined object of 2 cursor objects?

Comment: Well, it's is harder to do as it requires knowledge in a wrapper class about what exactly the methods you call in chained objects do. Let's say your objects have `.empty()` method and `.nonempty()` method and `.count()` method and `.peek()` method -- what the corresponding implementation in wrapper should do for each of those? I'm afraid you'll need to separately redefine each of those in the wrapper.

Comment: Do you feel like this is the only option here? May there be another approach to solve this issue?